# Does -> and [ ], both are same thing for php array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with Drupal and I find the several places following way of displaying php variables,

```
$language->language
```

in code

```
<?php print $language->language; ?>
```

now I am wondering whether,

`$language['language']` and `$language->language` are both same things,

Thanks

Comment: Please read about the difference between an _object_ and an _array_. Objects: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php Arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php Objects are kind of "active" data collections, whilst arrays are strictly passive containers.

Comment: Thanks to all, I was just in need of that clue, now I got it is array vs object, now I can refer there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,

```
$language['language']
```

is way of accessing array values using indexes. 
where as

```
$language->language
```

is way of accessing properties of object.

Comment: Thanks, I was just needed that clue..

Comment: No problem at all :)